# TweetSharp get followers count

Tags: .net, twitter

Does anyone know how to use TweetSharp to get some account's follower count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the friends and followers count from the TwitterUser object. To fetch a user directly:

```
 var twitter = FluentTwitter.CreateRequest()
            .Users().ShowProfileFor("jimbob").AsJson();

 var response = twitter.Request();
 var user = response.AsUser();
 Console.Writeline( "jimbob has {0} followers", user.FollowersCount);
```

User objects are also returned with individual TwitterStatus objects (i.e. tweets), so you can get them straight from there and avoid making another call as well:

```
 var twitter = FluentTwitter.CreateRequest()
            .Statuses().OnHomeTimeline().AsJson();

 var response = twitter.Request();
 var tweets = response.AsTweets();
 foreach ( var tweet in tweets )
 {
     Console.Writeline( "Posted by {0}, who has {1} followers", tweet.User.ScreenName, tweet.User.FollowersCount);
 }
```

Comment: Hi I came across your answer however I am using version 2.0, and 'FluentTwitter' does not exist any more, do you know how to do this in the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but this works for the new version better than nityan's answer, since Twitter's API doesn't return all their followers at once.

Basically just do a search for the account you want and it returns their profile including follower count.

```
const string consumerKey = "consumerKey";
const string consumerSecret = "consumerSecret";
const string accessToken = "accessToken";
const string accessTokenSecret = "accessTokenSecret";

string handleToSearchFor = "stackoverflow";

var service = new TwitterService(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
service.AuthenticateWith(accessToken, accessTokenSecret);

var users = service.SearchForUser(new SearchForUserOptions { Q = handleToSearchFor});
foreach (var user in users)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} has {1} followers and follows {2} people!", user.ScreenName, user.FollowersCount, user.FriendsCount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Method() {    
    IList<TwitterUser> twitterFollowers = null;
    ListFollowersOptions options = new ListFollowersOptions();

    options.ScreenName = screenName;
    twitterFollowers = service.ListFollowers(options);

    int followersCount = twitterFollowers.Count;
}
```